# SMTPAuthenticationError at / Username and Password not accepted

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Пытаюсь отправить письмо себе на почту через django. 
Settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'send_email.apps.SendEmailConfig',
]
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@mail.ru'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*********'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'fall'
DEFAULT_TO_EMAIL = 'myemail@mail.ru'
```

views.py:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError

def send_email(request):
    subject = request.POST.get('your-name', '')
    message = request.POST.get('tel-346', '')
    from_email = "ldr200@mail.ru"
    print(subject)
    print(request)
    if subject and message and from_email:
        try:
            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['ldr200@mail.ru'], fail_silently=False,)
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')

    else:
        # In reality we'd use a form class
        # to get proper validation errors.
        return HttpResponse('Make sure all fields are entered and valid.')


def hello_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return send_email(request)
    else:
        return render(request, 'hello_page/main1.html')
```

всё это выдает ошибку:

```
"SMTPAuthenticationError at /
(535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials p18sm11520343lfh.24 - gsmtp')"
```

Почему она появляется и как её устранить?

Answer (score 1):

smtp.mail.ru но у вас  gmail.com

Comment: поменял и получил вот это: "TimeoutError at /
[WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера"